# Bokeh server dev mode missing file

Tags: python, bokeh

I am running bokeh server as :

```
bokeh serve myScript.py --dev myScript.py
```

It start as usual but on change of myScript.py Bokeh server does not reload. Instead it prints following error:

> D:\Anaconda\envs\pyt27_2\python.exe: can't open file
>   'D:\Anaconda\envs\pyt27_2\Scripts\bokeh': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory

I have this bokeh file, so I am confused what can be wrong.

Comment: The same issue is mentioned in github issues at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8529. Can you try that once?

Comment: omg I really forget about that... Thank you very much though

Comment: Wait a min. You are `johny1614`. Such a small world :)